# Delete duplicate features by value and relative position in QGIS

Tags: delete, position, duplicates

I have a point layer with features of which some share the same date (fieldname: 'Datum' with format: "dd.MM.yyyy"). The date that is shared by some features is not a single specific one but can be any possible date.

I want to select all features that share the same date AND are close together (for example less than 500 meters away from each other).

I then want to keep only one of those features and erase the other one. Which one to delete can be random.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of the forum I found the solution.

**1.) Find point features that are closer together than a certain distance:**

[Points within certain distance to each other](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305965/points-within-certain-distance-to-each-other)

**2.) From those point features within a certain area (i.e. distance to each other) AND the same value of a given field, keep only one:**

[Select point features within same polygon AND with same field value QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/478664/select-point-features-within-same-polygon-and-with-same-field-value-qgis)